# Pop up Dialog/Finder box does not appear Mac

Tags: file-upload, dialog, popupwindow

When I try to upload an image on my Mac and click on "upload" a dialog box does not appear.  Normally a pop-up that's similar to the Finder window displays and allows me to choose a file.  I checked Chrome, Safari, and Firefox and the upload dialog would not appear while on any of them.  I also checked GMail attachment link and nothing happened there either.  Just spinning.  What extension or application helps with this?  I'm afraid I may have deleted it the other day when I was trying to create more space on my Mac...

Answer (score 0):

I also began having issues with my Finder window in general and after looking for some answers online I think something was happening with the new Sonoma 14.1 OS version and my iCloud trying to sync.  I disabled my dynamic screensaver because someone mentioned that helped, and I removed the iCloud drive, and then restarted my computer.  Now the Finder window pops up for uploads, and seems to be working in general.